# Solidity. Find whether a key exists in a mapping. Then get its value

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging, error

I have a simple mapping:

```
 mapping(address => string) professorsExam;
```

How can I check if `msg.sender` is a key in this mapping, and if it is, get its value? If it isn't I should return something.

```
string memory professorsExamHash = professorsExam[msg.sender];  // The hash of the exam owned by msg.sender
if(professorsExamHash == 0x0){
    return "No exam hash asociated with this professor address";
}
```

This doesn't work,

> TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types string memory and
>   int_const 0

I have tried many other things. But `==` isn't compatible between anything so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the bytes of the value. You do this by converting the string to bytes and checking the length. If it is greater than 0, than it exists.

Your new code would be as follows:

```
if(bytes(professorsExamHash).length == 0){
    return "No exam hash asociated with this professor address";
}
```